# Dictionary filtering with multiple sequential conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary dict = {} with the following layout where X is a force and Y is a cycle. I want to filter out the forces of the current cycle which are lower than the maximum force of the previous cycle.

```
Key1   X     Y  
      100    3
      200    3
      300    3
      400    3  
      500    3
      600    3
      100    5
      200    5
      300    5
      400    5
      500    5
      600    5
      700    5          
      100    8
      200    8
      300    8
      400    8
      500    8
      600    8
      700    8      
      800    8
```

Now my goal is to filter out the columns by comparing X and Y like:

```
dict_filter = {}
for k, v in dict.items():
    if (Y - Y.min() == 0) is True:
      dict_filter[k] = v
    elif X(Y) < X(Y.shift(-1)).max()
      dict_filter[k] = v
```

I know that it is not working like that but that is my general idea about it. The goal is to be like

```
Key1   X     Y  
      100    3
      200    3
      300    3
      400    3  
      500    3
      600    3
      700    5
      800    8
```

But for all key, value pairs in the dictionary. I tried many different conditions but whatever I do, dict_filter stays empty and nothing happens. I first tried just to filter it by the minimum Y-value.

```
dict_filter= {k: v for k, v in res.items() if (v['Y'] - v['Y'].min() == 0 is True)}
```

Maybe I should also add Y into the for-loop? Like:

```
for k,v,Y in dict.items()
```

So it iterates over the Y-value aswell?

Comment: What are X and Y? Do you have a nested dictionary? Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Comment: It is not a nested dictionary. It is a dictionary of dataframes. X is a force and Y is a cycle. I want to filter out the forces of the current cycle which are lower than the maximum force of the previous cycle.

Comment: `X is a force and Y is a cycle.` In programming terminology this means little. Can you provide a runnable **[mcve]**?

Comment: Not right now. I could look into it. I get the data from a file so before I can provide it I have to write it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you just want to get the minimal Y for each X? Try this:

Imagine your input file is like

```
100 3
200 3
300 3
400 3
...
```

The dict will be:

```
d = {}
for line in s.split('\n'):
    parts = line.trim().split()
    x = int(parts[0])
    y = int(parts[1])
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
result = dict((k, min(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())
```